# Android: Push data from service to activity

Tags: android, service, callback

I am using ICP in order to create a communication between activity and service.
I can call service's method from activity using the interface.

My problem is that sometimes i want to push data from service to activity, I want to call activity;s method from service. for example : updateTextView(String msg);

I don't want to use broadcast because i read that it is not very performant.

I read something about some callback but I don't know how to create it and where to put it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can put a bundle you start the service with. Populate that bundle in the Service that you want to pass back to the Activity. Then pass the bundle back to the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this via Handler. You create a field Handler in your activity, and other of the same class in your Service and onServiceConnected method call a Service's method setHandler. Then, you can  send messages to handler field of Activity via handler of the Service.

```
public class mService extends Service{
 private myHandler handler;
.....
  public void setHandler(myHandler activityHandler){
 this.handler=activityHandler;
 }
}

public class Activity extends Activity{
  private myHandler activityHandler;
  ....
  public class myHandler extends Handler{

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){

            switch(msg.what){
            //Implement this
          }
      }
}   
      private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
                    .....
                mService= binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
                mService.setHandler(dHandler);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                mBound = false;
            }
        };
}
```